# Inconveniente con la función CreatePivotTable en tabla dinámica en Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, excel-2010

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia y agradezco su colaboración  con el siguiente requerimiento que se me presenta al intentar crear una tabla dinámica haciendo uso del lenguaje de programación VBA de Excel:

Primero que todo vale la pena aclarar que me estoy basando en el libro con nombre “Programación con Microsoft EXCEL 2002 MACROS Y VISUAL BASIC PARA APLICACIONES”
Un libro que ya tiene 20 años de pero bueno sin mas preámbulo el código es el siguiente:

Al ejecutar dicho código, me aparece el siguiente error como se ve en la figura 1:

```
Sub CrearTabla()
Dim miCache As PivotCache
Dim miTabla As PivotField
Dim miCampo As PivotField
Dim miElemento As PivotItem

'Workbooks.Open "Pedidos.dbf"     ' Pedidos.dbf, investigar la extensión .dbf de que es   OJO AQUI DEBEMOS DE DARLE LA RUTA AL ARCHIVO
Workbooks.Open "D:\Macros Utiles VBA Excel\Pedidos.dbf"
'Set miCaché = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "Pedidos")
Set miCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "Pedidos")

Worksheets.Add
Set miTabla = miCache.CreatePivotTable(Cells(1))

'Set miTabla = miCache.CreatePivotTable(Cells(1)   ' 8 DE OCTUBRE
'Set miTabla = miCache.CreatePivotTable(Range("a1:d25")
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("UDS")   ' Se ha producido el error '424' en tiempo de ejecución    Se requiere un objeto
miCampo.Orientation = xlDataField  'Se ha producido el error '424' en tiempo de ejecución    Se requiere un objeto
miCampo.NumberFormat = "#, ##0"

'Set miCampo = Hoja1.miTabla.PivotFields("ESTADO")   'Puesto el 8 de Octubre 2022
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("ESTADO")
miCampo.Orientation = xlRowField
miCampo.Orientation = xlColumnField
miCampo.Orientation = xlPageField
miCampo.CurrentPage = "WA"
miCampo.CurrentPage = "CA"
miCampo.Orientation = xlHidden
miTabla.AddFields "CATEGORÍA", "ESTADO", "CANAL"
miTabla.AddFields Array("ESTADO", "CANAL"), "PRECIO", _
    "FECHA"
miCampo.Position = 2

Set miElemento = miCampo.PivotFields("WA")
miElemento.Position = 1
miElemento.Name = "Washington"
miElemento.Name = miElemento.SourceName
miElemento.Visible = False
miElemento.Visible = True
Set miElemento = miTabla.PivotFields("Canal").PivotItems("Minorista")
miElemento.ShowDetail = False
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("Neto")
  miCampo.Orientation = xlDataField
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("Datos")
miCampo.Orientation = xlColumnField
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("Suma de NETO")
miCampo.Orientation = xlHidden
Set miCampo = miTabla.PivotFields("Suma de UDS")
miCampo.Function = xlAverage
miCampo.Name = "Prom Uds"
miTabla.DataBodyRange.Select
Range("D4").Select
Set miElemento = ActiveCell.PivotItem
miElemento.DataRange.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Al ejecutar dicho código, me aparece el siguiente error como se ve en la figura 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al dar clic en Depurar me muestra la siguiente línea de código:

```
Set miTabla = miCaché.CreatePivotTable(Cells(1))
```

Como se ve en la figura 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Prueba a grabar una macro mientras creas una tabla dinámica y ajustas ese código.

Comment: Si se reemplaza `Cells(1)` por `ActiveCell`, el código funciona. `Cells` aquí es `Application.Cells`, es decir todas las celdas, y `Cells(1)` son todas la celdas de la 1ª fila; 65.536 celdas; demasiadas.